# DatePickerDialog with theme Holo Light?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-theme

How is it possible to get a DatePickerDialog with Holo Light theme?

When creating a `DatePickerDialog` as follows:

```
 DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(new ContextThemeWrapper(this,
                    android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar), 
    new DateListener(v), mTime.year, mTime.month, mTime.monthDay);
```

or with theme `android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light` or `android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog`, I get a date picker with a standard title and standard buttons. I tried to use a custom theme with a holo light parent too, but it didn't work either. It seems to work with theme `android.R.style.Theme_Holo`, but the result is a dark background (as expected), but I would like to have a light one.

The application's android.jar is of version 14, the application is running on a divice with android version 3.2.

I have seen an example here: http://as400samplecode.blogspot.com/2011/10/android-datepickerdialog.html, which shows a `DatePickerDialog` with the holo light theme, the way I would like to have it. I don't know why it doesn't work with my setup.

Thank you for help.

Comment: put android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" in your activity tag in manifest.xml

Comment: @PadmaKumar thank you for the comment. I will try what you suggested. But generally, I would like to use a theme with parent android:Theme.Holo.Light.DialogWhenLarge for the activity.

Comment: @PadmaKumar I put android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" in the activity tag in the manifest.xml and it didn't change anything (I think, because I use the 'ContextThemeWrapper').

Comment: @Julia: did you ever find the solution to this?

Comment: @AdrianGrigore: no, unfortunately, I didn't.

Comment: @Julia I'm not sure what's the problem here. I tested your code with `android.R.style.Theme_Holo` and with `android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light` and both gave me the same dialog, with the same buttons. The only difference was the dark/light style. What seems to be the problem then? Perhaps you should update your question with screenshots?

Answer (score 18):

The `DatePickerDialog` has a constructor which accepts a theme

```
DatePickerDialog(Context context, int theme, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener callBack, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
```

just update your code to include the style you want without the need for a `ContextThemeWrapper`

```
DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar, 
new DateListener(v), mTime.year, mTime.month, mTime.monthDay);
```

It's working for me that way.

Comment: Is android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar available for versions < 2.0 ?

Comment: @Yume117: No the Holo Theme was added to Honeycomb 3.0

Answer (score 3):

Read this Android *DatePickerDialog example code* which includes how to use *different Themes* in *DatePickerDialog*.

Here is the [such one](http://android--examples.blogspot.com/2015/05/how-to-use-datepickerdialog-in-android.html).

DatePickerDialog Constructor which support to define Theme.

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();  
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);  
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);  
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);  
return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK, this, year, month, day);
```

Comment: While this answer might be correct, it is better to add some explanation. I f the provided link becomes invalid, the answer will make no sense anymore at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

For Material style this worked for me:

```
int datePickerThemeResId = 0;
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
    datePickerThemeResId = android.R.style.Theme_Material_Light_Dialog;
}
new DatePickerDialog(
    context,
    datePickerThemeResId,
    (view, year, month, dayOfMonth) -> {},
    year,
    month,
    day
).show();
```