# DatePickerDialog, style and compatibility

Tags: android, datepicker

I'm using the DatePickerDialog and it's displayed via DialogFragment(from support library).

The datepicker dialog displays correctly in ICS, if android:theme 
is set to "android:Theme.Light". But if it is set to @android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
Datepickerdialog displays as if in the Android versions below 3.0

Since the app do not display the title bar, we need to use "NoTitleBar".

I'm not sure which value I need to set for android:theme to make 
Datepickerdialog to work properly in ICS. I tried changing the 
style and theme using the setStye() in DialogFragment, but it didn't work.
Any suggestions which theme I need to set?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this thread helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9278780/datepickerdialog-with-theme-holo-light